# Expanding lists as columns within an existing dataframe

Tags: r, json, dataframe, list

I'll preface this by saying I'm relatively new to R and I'm what you might call a "brute force" learner -- I don't study the language, learn it, then put it into practice. Rather, I start with a modest conceptual understanding, then through a combination of Google and extensive trial and error, arrive at a solution for a specific task I'm trying to complete, and learn from each experience. So please forgive any mistaken references on my part. But I've made my way through several steps of the current task, and I find myself now stuck close to the end.

Bottom line issue is that I have a dataframe with several columns that contain lists, which should be tied to the id value in its row, and I can't figure out how to unpack it all in the way that I want.

```
# A tibble: 6 × 17
  id    start_date home_team away_team is_live is_popular sport league odds.1.sports_book_n…¹ odds.1.name odds.1.price odds.1.bet_points odds.1.is_main
  <chr> <chr>      <chr>     <chr>     <lgl>   <lgl>      <chr> <chr>  <list>                 <list>      <list>       <list>            <list>        
1 3404… 2023-09-2… Los Ange… San Fran… FALSE   FALSE      base… MLB    <chr [6]>              <chr [6]>   <int [6]>    <dbl [6]>         <lgl [6]>     
2 1481… 2023-09-2… Washingt… Atlanta … FALSE   FALSE      base… MLB    <chr [6]>              <chr [6]>   <int [6]>    <dbl [6]>         <lgl [6]>     
3 1216… 2023-09-2… Philadel… New York… FALSE   FALSE      base… MLB    <chr [28]>             <chr [28]>  <int [28]>   <dbl [28]>        <lgl [28]>    
4 2568… 2023-09-2… San Dieg… St. Loui… FALSE   FALSE      base… MLB    <chr [465]>            <chr [465]> <int [465]>  <dbl [465]>       <lgl [465]>   
5 4064… 2023-09-2… Oakland … Detroit … FALSE   FALSE      base… MLB    <chr [64]>             <chr [64]>  <int [64]>   <dbl [64]>        <lgl [64]>    
6 3854… 2023-09-2… Texas Ra… Seattle … FALSE   FALSE      base… MLB    <chr [66]>             <chr [66]>  <int [66]>   <dbl [66]>        <lgl [66]>    
# ℹ abbreviated name: ¹​odds.1.sports_book_name
# ℹ 4 more variables: odds.1.is_live <list>, odds.1.market_name <list>, odds.1.selection <list>, odds.1.selection_line <list>
```

Backstory: I'm querying an sports odds API that requires me to pass a GameID as part of the request. So far, I've managed to:

1. Retrieve a list of available games from the API
2. Subset that response into a dataframe of GameIDs
3. Create and run a separate API call that loops over the GameIDs and returns all the data in a nested list -- using map()
4. Unpack that initial result -- using rrapply() -- to get the tibble shown above.

I feel like this should be fairly straightforward at this point, but I've not been able to search on the right combination of keywords apparently that points me to an existing discussion that is helpful in my specific case. I've tried a variety of unlist, rbind, map_*, and other functions to no avail.

Columns 1:9 are the game-specific details and need to be retained. Columns 10:17 are all lists containing specific markets/lines and need to be expanded according to the game they're currently associated with. For what it's worth, all of the list-columns should end up with the same length.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Edit to add dput(head())... I'm cutting it off because even with head() it's limiting to six top-level rows and not the list rows, which get very long. The other list columns are similar, but I'm also adding a screenshot of the df in case that helps as well.

```
structure(list(id = c("34048-80389-2023-09-24-16", "14818-36174-2023-09-24-15", 
"12164-37900-2023-09-24-15", "25683-25135-2023-09-24-13", "40644-76765-2023-09-24-13", 
"38548-10478-2023-09-24-11"), start_date = c("2023-09-24T19:00:00-04:00", 
"2023-09-24T18:35:00-04:00", "2023-09-24T18:05:00-04:00", "2023-09-24T16:10:00-04:00", 
"2023-09-24T16:07:00-04:00", "2023-09-24T14:35:00-04:00"), home_team = c("Los Angeles Dodgers", 
"Washington Nationals", "Philadelphia Phillies", "San Diego Padres", 
"Oakland Athletics", "Texas Rangers"), away_team = c("San Francisco Giants", 
"Atlanta Braves", "New York Mets", "St. Louis Cardinals", "Detroit Tigers", 
"Seattle Mariners"), is_live = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE), is_popular = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE), sport = c("baseball", "baseball", "baseball", "baseball", 
"baseball", "baseball"), league = c("MLB", "MLB", "MLB", "MLB", 
"MLB", "MLB"), odds.1.sports_book_name = list(c("FanDuel", "FanDuel", 
"FanDuel", "FanDuel", "FanDuel", "FanDuel"), c("FanDuel", "FanDuel", 
"FanDuel", "FanDuel", "FanDuel", "FanDuel"), c("FanDuel", "FanDuel", 
"FanDuel", "FanDuel", "FanDuel", "FanDuel", "FanDuel", "FanDuel", 
"FanDuel", "FanDuel", "FanDuel", "FanDuel", "FanDuel", "FanDuel", 
"FanDuel", "FanDuel", "FanDuel", "FanDuel", "FanDuel", "FanDuel", 
"FanDuel", "FanDuel", "FanDuel", "FanDuel", "FanDuel", "FanDuel", 
"FanDuel", "FanDuel"), c("FanDuel", "FanDuel", "FanDuel", "FanDuel", 
"FanDuel", "FanDuel", "FanDuel", "FanDuel", "FanDuel", "FanDuel", 
"FanDuel", "FanDuel", "FanDuel", "FanDuel", "FanDuel", "FanDuel", 
"FanDuel", "FanDuel", "FanDuel", "FanDuel", "FanDuel", "FanDuel",
```

[screenshot of df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdHwR.png)

Comment: It would be helpful if you pasted the output of `dput(<your data frame>)` to your question. The way you have it posted now, we can see they are list-columns but not their content. `dput` will preserve the structure and is easily used by those trying to help.

Comment: Hi Simms34, welcome to Stack Overflow! If dput(df) is too large, then dput(head(df)) would be great instead

Comment: Since it appears that columns 10-17 are all the same length, you might be able to use `tidyr::unnest(df, 10:17)`.

Comment: sorry simms you seemed to have cut off even the `dput(head(df)), which makes it kind of useless. Please post the entire dput(head(df))!!! Your example ends half way through a list col

Comment: @Mark Tried to add the whole thing in, and got "Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 73535" lol ... so yeah, that's not gonna work.

Comment: no, what I mean to say is, you didn't add all of the dput(head(df))

Comment: unless you are actually talking about the dput(head()), in which case...jeez!

Comment: That said, @r2evans suggestion worked perfectly ... I knew it had to be something relatively simple lol. Thank you!!

Comment: @Mark yeah, that was the dput(head)) ... the one game had 435 or so items within the list columns, so the character count adds up pretty fast

Comment: FYI @Simms34, the moment any one of those is a different length, things become much less deterministic. Glad it helped, good luck!

Comment: I think in the case @r2evans outlined, it might be better to replace `10:17` with `odds.1.sports_book_name:last_col()`

Comment: I actually mis-counted the columns in my original post ... it should be 9:17, not 10:17. It's all the columns that start with "odds.1.__" that need expanding. But either way, it did the trick.

Comment: @r2evans I gathered as much when it comes to list length, which is why I wanted to make a point of specifying they would be the same. Given the nature of this particular request, I'm not concerned with having to deal with unequal lengths just yet, but when I do, I'm sure I'll be back lol